A way to add text from XML-TEI into a PAGEXML file?
I have recognized a layout of an image and have the PAGEXML with the proper text regions and text lines, and an XML-TEI file.
The XML-TEI file has the required text line-for-line, in plaintext, and each corresponding text region is separated by <pb n="n.n">.
Example:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
  <teiHeader>
    <fileDesc>
      <titleStmt>
<title>Sample title</title>
      </titleStmt>
      <publicationStmt>
<p/>
      </publicationStmt>
      <sourceDesc>
<msDesc>
  <msIdentifier>
    <idno>sample idno</idno>
  </msIdentifier>
</msDesc>
      </sourceDesc>
    </fileDesc>
  </teiHeader>
  <text>
    <body>
      <ab>
<milestone unit="sheet" n="2"/>
<pb n="2.1"/>
Text line 1
Text line 2
Text line 3
Text line 4
<pb n="2.2"/>
Text line 1
Text line 2
Text line 3
Text line 4
</ab>
    </body>
  </text>
</TEI>

The PAGEXML has the <Coords points="x"> and <Baseline points="y">, as stated earlier, but it lacks the                                          <TextEquiv> <Unicode>Text</Unicode> </TextEquiv>
after those two lines.
Also, after each text region, there should be the contents of each line:
<TextEquiv>
                <Unicode>Text line 1&#13;
Text line 2&#13;
Text line 3&#13;
Text line 4</Unicode>
            </TextEquiv>

Example of a PAGEXML without the text lines:


   
```
 
        Transkribus
        2024-09-27T13:23:34.073+02:00
        2024-09-30T14:19:53.427+02:00
        
    
    
        
            
                
                
                
                
            
        
        
            
            
                
                
            
            
                
                
            
            
                
                
            
            
                
                
            
        
        
            
            
                
                
            
            
                
                
            
            
                
                
            
            
                
                
            
        
    

```
And here is an example of what I want to achieve in the output, with the XML files above as input:
 <Metadata>
        <Creator>Transkribus</Creator>
        <Created>2024-09-27T13:23:34.073+02:00</Created>
        <LastChange>2024-09-30T14:19:53.427+02:00</LastChange>
        <TranskribusMetadata docId="docID" pageId="pageId" pageNr="178" tsid="tsid" status="IN_PROGRESS" userId="userid" imgUrl="imgUrl&amp;fileType=view" xmlUrl="https://files.transkribus.eu/Get?id=ID" imageId="imageId"/>
    </Metadata>
    <Page imageFilename="page.jpg" imageWidth="3000" imageHeight="1690">
        <ReadingOrder>
            <OrderedGroup id="ro_1727699123599" caption="Regions reading order">
                <RegionRefIndexed index="0" regionRef="tr_1"/>
                <RegionRefIndexed index="1" regionRef="tr_2"/>
                <RegionRefIndexed index="2" regionRef="tr_3"/>
                <RegionRefIndexed index="3" regionRef="tr_4"/>
            </OrderedGroup>
        </ReadingOrder>
        <TextRegion orientation="0.0" id="tr_1" custom="readingOrder {index:0;}">
            <Coords points="235,176 235,1330 650,1330 650,176"/>
            <TextLine id="tr_1_tl_1" custom="readingOrder {index:0;}">
                <Coords points="coords points"/>
                <Baseline points="baseline points"/>
                <TextEquiv>
                    <Unicode>Text line 1</Unicode>
                </TextEquiv> 
            </TextLine>
            <TextLine id="tr_1_tl_2" custom="readingOrder {index:1;}">
                <Coords points="coords points"/>
                <Baseline points="baseline points"/>
                <TextEquiv>
                    <Unicode>Text line 2</Unicode>
                </TextEquiv> 
            </TextLine>
            <TextLine id="tr_1_tl_3" custom="readingOrder {index:2;}">
                <Coords points="coords points"/>
                <Baseline points="baseline points"/>
                <TextEquiv>
                    <Unicode>Text line 3</Unicode>
                </TextEquiv> 
            </TextLine>
            <TextLine id="tr_1_tl_4" custom="readingOrder {index:3;}">
                <Coords points="coords points"/>
                <Baseline points="baseline points"/>
                <TextEquiv>
                    <Unicode>Text line 4</Unicode>
                </TextEquiv> 
            </TextLine>
            <TextEquiv>
                <Unicode>Text line 1&#13;
Text line 2&#13;
Text line 3&#13;
Text line 4</Unicode>
            </TextEquiv>
        </TextRegion>
        <TextRegion orientation="0.0" id="tr_2" custom="readingOrder {index:1;}">
            <Coords points="coords points"/>
            <TextLine id="tr_2_tl_1" custom="readingOrder {index:0;}">
                <Coords points="coords points"/>
                <Baseline points="baseline points"/>
                <TextEquiv>
                    <Unicode>Text line 1</Unicode>
                </TextEquiv> 
            </TextLine>
            <TextLine id="tr_2_tl_2" custom="readingOrder {index:1;}">
                <Coords points="coords points"/>
                <Baseline points="baseline points"/>
                <TextEquiv>
                    <Unicode>Text line 2</Unicode>
                </TextEquiv> 
            </TextLine>
            <TextLine id="tr_2_tl_3" custom="readingOrder {index:2;}">
                <Coords points="coords points"/>
                <Baseline points="baseline points"/>
                <TextEquiv>
                    <Unicode>Text line 3</Unicode>
                </TextEquiv> 
            </TextLine>
            <TextLine id="tr_2_tl_4" custom="readingOrder {index:3;}">
                <Coords points="coords points"/>
                <Baseline points="baseline points"/>
                <TextEquiv>
                    <Unicode>Text line 4</Unicode>
                </TextEquiv> 
            <TextEquiv>
                <Unicode>Text line 1&#13;
Text line 2&#13;
Text line 3&#13;
Text line 4</Unicode>
            </TextEquiv>
            </TextLine>
        </TextRegion>
    </Page>
</PcGts>

I could not find a way to implement that in Python(the only programming language I know to a proper extent), and am relatively new to programming/coding as a whole. Is there a way to implement that and to check if the PAGEXML file is over(probably by checking for </Page>) and open the next PAGEXML file?(Given that the filename is always a number, like 1.xml, 2.xml and so on for each file)
Thanks in advance!
